# Using Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I would like to solve the following problem using lagrange multipliers:

Find the minimum and maximum of the following function: $f(x,y) = x^2+x+2y^2$ on the disc {$(x;y);x^2+y^2\leq 1$}

I believe that the Lagrange function would be: $L(x,y,\lambda) = x^2+x+2y^2+\lambda(x^2+y^2-1)$ But other than that I don't how to go about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the first stept solve the system $$f_x=2x+1=0$$ and $$f_y=4y=0$$
in the second consider the function $$f(x,y,\lambda)=x^2+x+2y^2+\lambda(x^2+y^2-1)$$
and solve the system
$$f_x=2x+1+\lambda2x=0$$
$$f_y=4y+\lambda2y=0$$
$$f_\lambda=x^2+y^2=1$$

Comment: ... thus there are 4 solutions $(x,y)=(1/2,\pm\sqrt{3}/2), (\pm1,0)$. It remains to find which ones give a max. or a min.